# How can I use reflection to dynamically cast one object to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I am trying to set up the following code:

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoadReport(string actionName, string reportInput, string reportCriteria)
{
    var type = Assembly.Load("Company.TaxCollection.Reports").GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == reportInput);
    var typeCriteria = Assembly.Load("Company.TaxCollection.Reports").GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == reportInput + "Criteria");
    var reportObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var reportObjectCriteria = Activator.CreateInstance(typeCriteria);
    IEnumerable<ReportCriteria> reportList = getReportCriteria(reportObject);
    foreach (ReportCriteria r in reportList)
    {
        reportObjectCriteria t = (reportObjectCriteria)r;
    }

    return Json(Url.Action(actionName, "Reports", reportList.Where(x => x.CriteriaName == reportCriteria)));
}
```

I get the error `reportObjectCriteria is a variable but is used like a type` within the foreach loop.

I have also tried not using a variable and just using Activator.CreateInstance directly, but that didn't work either.

```
foreach (ReportCriteria r in reportList)
{
Activator.CreateInstance(typeCriteria) t = 
(Activator.CreateInstance(typeCriteria)) r;
}
```

The purpose of these lines of code is to cast the ReportCriteria object to another type dynamically during runtime.  The object type to cast to is decided by the reportInput parameter in the controller.

Comment: casting is a compile time feature, not a runtime one like reflection.

Comment: @DanielA.White It is?!? Then what is MSIL opcode 0x74 `castclass` for? [OpCodes.Castclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.castclass?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Is there a reason to not use libraries like AutoMapper(https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html) for this purpose? I hope there is, if not it feels like re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance creates an instance of a type. In what you have written, reportObjectCriteria is an object of type typeCriteria

Comment: An object can only be cast to a type in the object's inheritance hierarchy, so one of your two types must derive from the other for this to work. Moreover in code, casting is done by wrapping a *type name* in parentheses--you can't just wrap a variable in parentheses and expect that to work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're not loading up a .dll dynamically at runtime, I would recommend using a library like [Automapper](https://automapper.org).  You can create multiple mappings like below and use conditional logic to determine which type to map to.

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceType, DestType1>();
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceType, DestType2>();
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceType, DestType3>();
});

DestType1 dt1 = mapper.Map<DestType1>(sourceTypeInstance);
DestType2 dt2 = mapper.Map<DestType2>(sourceTypeInstance);
DestType3 dt3 = mapper.Map<DestType3>(sourceTypeInstance);
```

The library is very feature rich where you can configure mappings to a much deeper levels and lists/arrays etc.